# Get parts of string after a certain word? Shell

Tags: shell

I have the following variable that contains a string displaying folders in a dir tree:

```
root/f1/f2/f3/f4/f5
root/f1/f2/f3/f4
root/f1/f2/f3
```

How would I go about removing everything that is before f2 so what I'm left with will be:

```
f2/f3/f4/f5
f2/f3/f4
f2/f3
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is probably the best choice here:

```
sed 's#.*/\(f2/\)#\1#' <<<"$var"
```

<sup>If you can assume GNU `sed` or BSD/OSX `sed`, you can make the command more readable with an *extended* regular expression (`-E`):

`sed -E 's#.*/(f2/)#\1#' <<<"$var"`</sup>

- alternative delimiter `#` is used for `sed`'s `s` function to facilitate *literal* use of `/` chars.
- `.*/\(f2/\)` matches everything from the start of the line through `/f2/`, and captures the `f2/` part in capture group 1.

  - Caveat: If your input paths contained *multiple* `/f2/` substrings, everything through the *last* occurrence of `/f2/` on the line would be matched.
- The matching part of the line is then replaced with `\1`, the string captured by the first (and only) capture group, effectively replacing the overall matched string with `f2/`, as desired, followed by the remainder of the input line.

Note that use of `<<<` to provide a variable value via stdin (a so-called [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString)) assumes `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` as the shell;
for a POSIX-compliant solution, use `printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed ...`

---

If the component to split by is stored in a *variable*, use, e.g.:

```
name='f2'
sed 's#.*/\('"$name"'/\)#\1#' <<<"$var"
```

Note that this will only work if `$name` contains neither the char. `#` nor any regular-expression metacharacters.

Also note how I've deliberate spliced in the - double-quoted - *shell* variable value into the otherwise *single*-quoted `sed` script, so as to make it clear which parts of the string are interpreted by the shell vs. `sed`.

Comment: This one also cuts f2.

Comment: @Daeto: No, it doesn't; please see my update for an explanation.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't if I type in the desired name but what if I have the name stored in a variable and type echo "$dirs" |  sed "s#.*/\($f2/\)#\1#" Could this be made to work? At the moment, it does delete whatever is stored in f2.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive explanation : ) I think I'll just use the variable to be safe. The missing f2 part is not that big of a deal.

Comment: @Daeto: What missing `f2` part? Both solutions - the literal and the variable-based ones - should preserve the `f2` / variable value, by virtue of the capture group (`\(...\)`) and the reference to it (`\1`) in the substitution string.

Answer (score 2):

vague question , vague answer

```
cut -f3- -d'/'
```

Comment: that should be `-f3-`

Comment: This does not seem to be working. It gives me "invalid option."

Comment: @Daeto  perhaps you need to provide more context as it does work for me

Comment: This answer effectively removes the first 2 path components from each input line, whatever they are.
While this happens to work for the sample data, both the title and the body of the question suggest that the line prefix
to remove should be based on a certain _word_ - which may or may not be at the same level of the path hierarchy in
all input lines, or the specific level may not be known in advance.